# D3 scatter plot not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to do a scatter plot using D3, but the points are not showing up. I can see circles generated in console though. Does anyone know why?

```
<script>
var rawData= ...;
function plotData(data){
          var concentration = [],
              uptake = [];
          for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
            concentration.push(data[i][3]);
            uptake.push(data[i][4]);
          }
          var width = 1000, height = 800;
          var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([d3.min(concentration)-20, d3.max(concentration)+20])
                    .range([0, width]);
          var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([d3.min(uptake)-20, d3.max(uptake)+20])
                    .range([height, 0]);
          var svg = d3.select("#scatter").append("svg")
                      .attr("width", width)
                      .attr("height", height);
          svg.selectAll("scatterplot")
             .data(uptake)
             .enter().append("svg:circle")
             .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d); } )
             .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return x(concentration[i]); } )
             .style("fill", "brown")
             .attr("r", 3);
     }
</script>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="plotData(rawData)">Visualize</button>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div id=scatter class=visualization></div>
</body>
```

The console output is here:
[image: Console Output]

Comment: By looking at the `cx` and `cy` values it seems like they're off the screen. I would revisit your `x` and `y` scales and ensure the right min/max values are calculated.

Comment: Your circles are all being plotted outside of your SVG (check the negative cx and cy values).  Is it possible that your numbers are stored as strings and that the max/min functions are giving wrong values as a result?

Comment: It looks to be like @AmeliaBR hinted...the code seems to be fine as can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2QRC/).

Comment: @AmeliaBR You are right. Do you mind submitting an answer? All I did is `concentration.push(parseFloat(data[i][3]));` and `uptake.push(parseFloat(data[i][4]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM inspector shows that your program is assigning negative cx and cy values to your points.  Since you're using linear scales to set these attributes, that suggests there is something wrong with your scale ranges or domains.

You're defining your scales as:

```
  var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(concentration)-20, d3.max(concentration)+20])
            .range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(uptake)-20, d3.max(uptake)+20])
            .range([height, 0]);
```

Assuming `width` and `height` are both positive numbers, the only way to get a negative output value from the scale is if you input a number that is less than the minimum domain value for the X scale or more than the maximum domain value on the Y scale -- which implies that the max/min functions aren't doing what you expect.

The most likely reason for unexpected results with `d3.max` and `d3.min` is that you're sorting numbers stored as strings.  It's even mentioned as a warning [in the API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_min) -- if your numbers are stored as strings, they will be compared alphabetically, not by numerical value.

Your linear scales still work because they coerce any input values to numbers, so you weren't getting any errors from the compiler, just unexpected results.

The solution (as @Boxuan discovered, see the comments) is simply to make sure that all your numbers are stored as such before passing them to the max and min functions.  Because you already have a loop in your code in which you're re-organizing your data, that is a natural place to do the parsing:

```
  for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
    concentration.push(parseFloat(data[i][3]));
    uptake.push(parseFloat(data[i][4]));
  }
```